# For which values of the parameter $p$ will the set of vectors $B = \{ b_1,b_2,b_3,b_4 \}$ form a basis in $\mathbb{R}^{4}$?

Tags: matrices, vectors

For which values of the parameter $p$ will the set of vectors $B =\{b_1,b_2,b_3,b_4\}$ form a basis in $\mathbb R^4$? For these values of $p$ determine the coordinate vector $[v]_B$.

$$\begin{align}
b_1 &= (\sqrt2,2,11,13)^T\\
b_2 &= (\sqrt2,9,15,12)^T\\
b_3 &= (\sqrt2,-19,4,19)^T\\
b_4 &=(\sqrt2,9,-5,p)^T\\
v &=(\sqrt2,-5,-48,-19+3p)^T\end{align}$$

As far as I understood we have to find these values of $p$ for which vectors $(b_1,b_2,b_3,b_4)$ will be independent and span the whole space.

Comment: After performing RREF, each column is a pivot.

Comment: NOT "span a subspace", span the entire space.

Comment: A basis for $R^n$ has three properties: (1) They span the space, (2) they are independent, (3) there are n vectors in the set.  Further, any two are sufficient to prove the third!  Here n= 4 and there are 4 vectors in the set so it is sufficient to show **either** that the vectors span $R^4$ **or** that they are independent.  Tianlalu is saying that they are independent.  (I don't see what v has to do with this problem.)

Answer (score 1):

The vectors form a basis if and only if the determinant of their matrix is non-zero.

$$\det \begin{pmatrix}
\sqrt2 & \sqrt2 & \sqrt2 & \sqrt 2 \\
2 & 9 & -19 & 9 \\
11 & 15 & 4 & -5 \\
13 & 12 & 19 & p
\end{pmatrix} = \begin{vmatrix}
\sqrt2 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
2 & 7 & -21 & 7 \\
11 & 4 & -7 & -16 \\
13 & -1 & 6 & p-13
\end{vmatrix} = \begin{vmatrix}
\sqrt2 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
2 & 7 & 0 & 0 \\
11 & 4 & 5 & -20 \\
13 & -1 & 3 & p-12
\end{vmatrix} = \begin{vmatrix}
\sqrt2 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
2 & 7 & 0 & 0 \\
11 & 4 & 5 & 0 \\
13 & -1 & 3 & p
\end{vmatrix} = p \cdot 35\sqrt2$$

So, the answer to the first part of the question is that these vectors form a basis iff $p \ne 0$.

To answer the second part we are looking for a set of numbers $x$, $y$, $z$, $w$, such that:

$$ x \mathbf{b}_1 + y\mathbf{b}_2 + x\mathbf{b}_3 + w\mathbf{b}_4 = \mathbf{v}$$

That is, we need to solve the following system of equations:

$$\begin{align*}
\sqrt2x + \sqrt2y + \sqrt2z + \sqrt2w &= \sqrt2 \\
2x + 9y -19z + 9w &= -5 \\
11x + 15y + 4z -5w &= -48 \\
13x + 12y + 19z + pw &= -19 + 3p
\end{align*}$$

Note that $p$ here is a parameter, not an unknown variable. Doing simple transformation (multiplying an equation by a number, adding or subtracting a multiple of an equation from another equation) we do the variable elimination:

$$\begin{align*}
x + y + z + w &= 1 \\
7y - 21z + 7w &= -7 \\
4y - 7z -16w &= -59 \\
-y + 6z + (p-13)w &= -32 + 3p
\end{align*}$$

$$\begin{align*}
x + y + z + w &= 1 \\
y - 3z + w &= -1 \\
 5z -20w &= -55 \\
 3z + (p-12)w &= -33 + 3p
\end{align*}$$

$$\begin{align*}
x + y + z + w &= 1 \\
y - 3z + w &= -1 \\
 z -4w &= -11 \\
  pw &= 3p
\end{align*}$$

Unraveling this from the bottom to the top we get: $w=3$, $z=1$, $y=-1$, and $x=-2$. Which means that the coordinates of $\mathbf{v}$ in this $\mathbf{B}$ basis are:

$$ [\mathbf{v}]_\mathbf{B} = (-2,-1,1,3). $$

Comment: How did you get v=−2b1−b2+b3+3b4 ? Not really clear to me

Comment: @MuradSh-ov I added a complete explanation for the second part now.
Originally I just assumed that the answer will be "nice" small integers and just played with it a little...

Answer (score 0):

Vectors form a basis of $\mathbb R^4$ if they are linearly independent and if they span the space. Since you have four vectors, and $\dim\mathbb R^4=4$, you just need to check their linear independence.

Vectors are linearly independent (L. I.) if the linear combination is equal to 0 only when all the coefficients are zero, that is:
$$\alpha b_1+\beta b_2 +\gamma b_3+ \delta b_4=0 \iff \alpha=\beta=\gamma=\delta=0\tag1$$
$(1)$ is a system of four equations, which you can solve to find the desired value(s) of $p$.